# My reputation is behaving very strange

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

I don't know what's the problem but I have added some screenshots below. My reputation yesterday was +200. And today my reputation is -251. Somebody please explain me what is happening. Thanks!

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: All those upvotes seem to have been in a short period of time, and the system/mods would have detected that these were from the same user.

So, all the rep you earned from that user got reversed when the system/mod deleted that account. The other 50rep probably got removed because of that question where you got +50/-50

Comment: btw why didn't you ask this on [android.se]?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Yesterday I thought: wow! I earned a lot of reputation on my answer. Today I get the message that is was an error and everything is reversed.

Comment: Yeah but it's there to protect you - if the votes had been *downvotes*, you would have lost quite a bit of rep! It keeps everything fair :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ And by "lost a BIT of rep", you mean 200? You do know that is the half of my total reputation:)

Comment: well it wouldn't have been 200 - because each downvote is only worth -2! But it would have been in between 50-100...?

Comment: We're looking into this.

Comment: It seems a little strange, that's a lot of "User Was Removed"s. Bear in mind this is an automated process - as TimPost said the humans now have to check it.

Comment: @TimPost Feel free to grab me in chat.

Comment: And it happens that you're not the only one who saw that strange behavior on your profile. When you tagged me in a comment [I was surprised](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22118924#22118924) to see a leap-bound in your reputation and noticed that many of your previous posts were upvoted. It seems that somebody tried to do a favor (or may be otherwise here) to you by serial upvoting but it was against network's policy. I guess only Mods can explain the details after looking into the matter.

Comment: @Firelord so mods can see who did upvote all my questions? I'm getting curious now, who wants to upvote all my answers? Anyway are there more people having problems like me?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab Mods can see voting trends. They can't see who voted where (so they can spot serial upvoting).

Comment: I'm not really sure about whether they can see or not, but I read somewhere on Meta that they can't! That said, hey! not just answers, your questions also got upvoted, didn't they? // And, you can Google or search on [meta.se] the terms like "voting reversal", "serial upvoting", "serial downvoting" and so on. You'll get posts having users with similar issues.

Comment: @Firelord - mods can't see voting details, only voting trends. So on any given post we **can't** see who voted.

Comment: @ChrisF Ah, that comment was in contrast to my previous one. Sorry for the mistake. You may take your comment back and I purged that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already explained in the comment section, this is a case of [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). To summarize it on your case,

> Voting fraud is the systematic voting against correct voting rationales. **Fraud most often happens with a single user continually voting (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time**. This is not considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.
>
> If mass voting continues to happen [...] from a single user, or looks just plain suspicious in general, moderators and/or developers may investigate the matter and disciplinary action may be taken against the users involved with the fraud.
>
> **Most often when you get unexpectedly serial upvoted, believe it or not, it's just a user trying to give you extra reputation**. They saw a post of yours that was extraordinarily helpful to them and they feel that going through your posts systematically and upvoting them is the appropriate way of granting you additional reputation (apparently they've forgotten about the bounty system).

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

The system *should* automatically detect and reverse it

> Every night around 03:00 UTC, a voting fraud detection script is run that looks for patterns such as these. It basically looks for users who have upvoted another user many times. The number is fairly low within a given amount of time (the exact mechanics are kept secret). When the system detects this pattern, all of the votes cast from that user to the user affected are reversed and it prints a "voting corrected" statement in the affected user's reputation history to indicate what has occurred.
>
> The value of the reversal could be anything, as it is the combined amount of all the votes being reversed (up and down, although most serial voting occurs in one direction). If you had reached the reputation cap, the value may show up as blank if none of the votes being reversed actually affected your reputation on that day.

But in your case, it didn't.

This behaviour occurred on:

- Jun 10, 13:10-13:17 UTC, netting 200 rep ([daily rep cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/241919)) from 31 upvotes (4 questions + 27 answers), and
- Jun 11, 12:42-12:45 UTC, netting 110 rep from 13 upvotes (4 questions + 9 answers)

for a total of 310 rep. Interestingly, the system didn't detect it, but a mod nuked the account instead, resulting in "User was removed" instead of "Voting corrected".

As I'm not a mod, I don't know whose account was nuked and why, but generally, we don't suppose to know unless the mod himself want to share it.